# Video camera is not available after waking up from sleep on macbook pro

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, skype

There is a problem on my mac with skype. When mac wakes up after sleep and I want to do a video call video is not available. Restarting skype doesn't help. After a very long time every time restarting mac when I need to do video call, I accidentally found that the problem is actually caused by Chrome. I don't really get how can chrome cause this issue. Restarting chrome every time is annoying as I am one of those guys with gazillion tabs open all the time. How can I track down what is actually causing it and how can I prevent this issue from happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is an OS X problem. Update to 10.9.2 to resolve it. You should really be on 10.9.2 anyway, since it has the vital SSL security fix! [More info here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/No-video-after-installing-OS-10-9-Mavericks/m-p/2956575/highlight/true#M64026)

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the link. I'll upgrade OS X and will monitor the situation. If it won't happen again after some time, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: On 10.9.2 after sleep my camera intermittently is reported as not existing on a MacBookPro (2012) in Skype and other video apps.